# How does $\sigma(T^*T)$ depends on $\sigma(T)$?

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators

Is there any relation between $\sigma(T^*T)$ and $\sigma(T)$ ?
Thank you!

Comment: Assuming $\sigma$ denote the spectrum and $T$ is a linear operator on a vector space: Yes, if $T=T^*$, i.e. $T$ is symmetric. Otherwise, not really. I mean $\sigma(T^*T)$ are the singular values while $\sigma(T)$ are the eigenvalues.

Comment: In general: Not at all.

Comment: @Surb The square roots of $\sigma(T^*T)$ are the singular values. Moreover, we talk about operators in possibly infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces.

Comment: At least if $T$ is normal, then $\sigma(T^*T) = \{|\lambda|^2 : \lambda\in\sigma(T)\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: In general (for a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space, and in particular any $n \times n$ matrix) $\max \sigma(T^* T) \ge \max \{|\lambda|^2: \lambda \in \sigma(T)\}$.

Comment: See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value#Singular_values_and_eigenvalues)